# JAMon / Performance Monitoring for .NET?

Tags: .net, performance, monitoring

I've been working on a Java app for several years, and have found JAMon to be a valuable tool for instrumenting the app to collect performance data.  Is anyone aware of a similar tool in the .NET world, or should I approach the problem differently for a .NET app?

Answer (score 1):

The best tools available to collect very rich information for both .NET application and any code running on Windows platform is ETW events (Event Tracing for Windows)

The CLR and .NET has a lot of useful counters that helps you fix problems right away, for example GC events, Lock Contention, Loader events.

You can also emit customer ETW events from your Application code.

For Reference Check out Event Tracing For Windows Results here 
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS462US462&sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Event+Tracing+For+Windows